# What term would best describe a need for friendship?

Tags: phrases

A friend of mine asked an interesting question today:

> If sexual frustration is need for sex and romantic frustration is need for romance, what is need for friendship?

Note: To be clear, this is saying Sexual Frustration is the want/need for sex, and Romantic frustration is the want/need for romance, not that they are the same thing.

And I can't come up with a good answer for that.  "Loneliness" was suggested, but that's not quite specific to needing a friend, so much as needing anybody at all.  And "socially frustrated" doesn't quite work either, because it implies being in a larger social group when that is not necessarily desired.

So, what term would better describe badly needing a friend?

Comment: I don't understand "sexual/romantic frustration" and "need for sex/romance" to mean the same.  There is a difference.

Comment: @Centaurus Yes, they are two separate things.  Sorry that isn't clear from the quote, I will try to clear that up.

Comment: Amical frustration?

Comment: [*friendlorn*](https://www.google.ca/search?q=friendlorn&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=KlksVYKgEcyryATCu4CoCw#q=%22friendlorn%22) ?

Answer (score 1):

> Isolated

He was becoming **isolated** and in desperate need of friendship.

Answer (score -1):

*yearning for friendship*

*craving for friendship*

*longing for friendship*

Comment: Possible reasons why this was downvoted?